# How can I increment an access type as if it were a C pointer?

Tags: ada

How to increment an address of access type like a pointer in C? I am new to Ada...

```
procedure main is
  type myarr is array(1..5)of integer; --creating array of 5 integer.
  myarr_var:aliased myarr:=(2,5,7,9,0); --setting 5 values
  type my_access is access all myarr; --creating access type (pointer)
  var:my_access:=myarr_var'access;  --holding address of 5 integer
begin;
  -- since var holds the address of myarr_var now i want to increment
  -- the address by adding 1 to print next value (5) as we do in c?

  put((var+1).all); --???
  -- i know this is bad but how to increment its base address of 
  -- var(pointer) so that it will point to next element 5?

end main;
```

Comment: why would you want to? Just index the access value as a normal array, dereferencing will then be implicit.

Comment: @egilhh i was asked in an interview

Comment: ok. Unless they are looking for someone to write an OS or possibly a compiler, they will _never_ (yes, bold statement) have pointer arithmetic in their Ada codebase.

Comment: `my_access` accesses a 5-element array of integers. So, given C semantics, `var++` should point to the next 5-element array of integers (probably 1 past the end of `myarr_var`).

Comment: You can't do what you ask for in your comment.  `Var` points to objects of type `Myarr`, while `Myarr_Var (2)` is an object of type `Integer`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instantiate [Interfaces.C.Pointers](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-B-3-2.html) to do C-style pointer arithmetic in Ada.

Best explained by example:

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Interfaces.C.Pointers;

procedure Access_Pointer_Arithmetic is

   type Myarr_Indices is range 1 .. 5;
   type Myarr is array (Myarr_Indices range <>) of aliased Integer;

   Myarr_Terminator : constant Integer := 0;

   package Myarr_Pointer_Arithmetic is new Interfaces.C.Pointers
     (Myarr_Indices, Integer, Myarr, Myarr_Terminator);

   use Myarr_Pointer_Arithmetic;

   Myarr_Var : aliased Myarr := (2, 5, 7, 9, 0);

   Var : Myarr_Pointer_Arithmetic.Pointer :=
              Myarr_Var(Myarr_Var'First)'access;

begin
   Put_Line(Integer'Image(Var.all));
   Increment(Var);
   Put_Line(Integer'Image(Var.all));
   Increment(Var);
   Put_Line(Integer'Image(Var.all));
   Increment(Var);
   Put_Line(Integer'Image(Var.all));

   Var := Var - 2;
   Put_Line(Integer'Image(Var.all));
end Access_Pointer_Arithmetic;
```

Running it:

```
C:\Ada\Sandbox\access_pointer_arithmetic
 2
 5
 7
 9
 5
```

This package provides single increment/decrement, addition and subtraction of ptrdiff_t, and both terminator-specified and fixed length element array retrieval.

(Mind running off the end of the array... :-)

Comment: thanks but what if i want to increment it by 2 or any no of bytes?

Comment: Please review the package to which I linked. There are '+' and '-' operators. Answer updated to demonstrate.

Comment: some unexpected behavior is noticed Put_Line(Integer'Image(Var.all));
   var:=var+5; -- it give 1,var+6 then 2 and if var+7 then 0,var+8 then -1 why please explain?

Comment: @SantoshGupta You're accessing beyond the end of the array. This is a bad thing. Since you're using C-style pointer incrementing, it's now your responsibility to stay in bounds.

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE :** I just found out that there's a standard package `Interfaces.C.Pointers` that directly supports C-style pointer arithmetic, and now I see that [Marc C.'s accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27842711/827263) covers its usage. You can probably ignore my answer, which discusses how you might do pointer arithmetic in Ada if `Interfaces.C.Pointers` didn't exist (which, in earlier versions of the language, it doesn't).

If you *really* want to do C-style pointer arithmetic on Ada access types, you can use the generic package `System.Address_To_Access_Conversions` to convert an object pointer type to `System.Address`, and the `System.Storage_Elements` package to perform C-like arithmetic on `System.Address` values.

Note that the target object type is a parameter to the `System.Address_To_Access_Conversions` generic package. The package itself defines the access type. You can't define your own access type and use it (at least not directly).

Keep in mind that C pointer arithmetic is defined in units of the size of the pointed-to object. So given:

```
int arr[10];
int *ptr = &arr[0];
```

the pointer value `ptr + 3` points to `arr[3]`, which is three `int`-sized chunks of memory past the location to which `ptr` points *not* necessarily three bytes.  The `"+"` and `"-"` operators in `System.Storage_Elements` work with offsets in storage elements (which are very likely equivalent to C's "bytes").

So if you have an Ada <strike>pointer</strike>, um, I mean access value, that refers to an element of an array of `Integer`s, then advancing to the *next* element of that array requires:

- Using `System.Address_To_Access_Conversions` to convert the access type to `System.Address`;
- Using the overloaded `"+"` operator in `System.Storage_Elements` to add the size of an `Integer` *in bytes* (`Integer'Max_Size_In_Storage_Elements`) to the `System.Address` value; and
- Using `System.Address_To_Access_Conversions` again to convert the `System.Address` value back to your access type.

An alternative might be to write C code to do whatever pointer arithmetic you need, and use `Interfaces.C` to call that code from your Ada program.

But it's very likely that you don't *need* to do pointer arithmetic in Ada. C has pointer arithmetic in the core language; it even defines array indexing in terms of pointer arithmetic. Ada does not. There's rarely a good reason to perform pointer arithmetic in Ada. Just let arrays be arrays, and let the compiler figure out how to generate the best code to access their elements. (That code will likely involve pointer arithmetic on the CPU instruction level.)

Comment: `System.Address_To_Access_Conversions` is a better choice than `Unchecked_Conversion`

Comment: @egilhh: Right, and `System.Storage_Elements` provides more or less C-like arithmetic on `System.Address` values. Thanks, I haven't used Ada  a lot lately.

Comment: You can use `t’Max_Size_In_Storage_Elements` to find out how many bytes `t` occupies.

Comment: Plus 1 for mentioning that the compiler will figure out how to generate code that does pointer arithmetic.  I suspect the main reason C has pointer arithmetic was to make it easy to take advantage of the PDP-11's auto-increment/decrement addressing modes without making the compiler too complex.  But compiler technology has advanced quite a bit in 40+ years.

Comment: @keith Thompson can you please give me small full example i new to ada i tired but  couldn't figure out.. i would be very thankful

Comment: @SantoshGupta, I doubt that Keith will give you a full example, as you have not yet provided a suitable use case for doing pointer/address/access arithmetic.

Comment: @jaco sparre Andersen  i was asked in an interview so from last 3 days i was earger to see how it s possible